# Create PHP table with for loop

Tags: php, for-loop, html-table

I would like to convert this html table to a PHP table with for loop,
the first row and column supposed to be empty.

```
<table border="1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>a</th>
        <th>b</th>
        <th>c</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>a1</td>
        <td>b1</td>
        <td>c1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>a2</td>
        <td>b2</td>
        <td>c2</td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

This what I've tried so far:

```
 $Rows = 2; 
$Cols = 3; 
echo '<table class="table">';
echo '<thead>;
<tr>
<td></td>';
    for($i=1;$i<=$Rows;$i++)
    { 

        for($j=1;$j<=$Cols;$j++)
        {
            echo '<td>' . "a ".$i .'</td>'; 
            echo '</tr>';

            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . "b ".$j. '</td>'; 
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</thead>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
```

and its horrible, and this what it supposed to be

[image: table image]

Comment: [Looping Through Arrays](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-php-5/0596005601/ch04s02.html)

Comment: `the first row and collumn supposed to be empty`->please explain. And also show your code effort what you tried so far?

Comment: i mean that first row and column is actually a blank box with no value in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
            <th>c</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php 
        for($i=1;$i<=2;$i++)
        {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo "a".$i; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo "b".$i; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo "c".$i; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: thanks appreciate it, but its just a standard html table and there is no sql

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
<table border="1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>a</th>
        <th>b</th>
        <th>c</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php 
    $i=1;
    $query=mysql_query("select * from table");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
    foreach($row as $r)
    {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $i++; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r['field1']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r['field2']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r['field3']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```